# Google Sheets: ImportJSON with key/value pair in request header

Tags: json, google-sheets, request, header

I'm trying to import a JSON payload into Google Sheets using the ImportJSON function from https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON.

The service I'm trying to consume requires an "authorization" key/value pair supplied in the request header:
https://groups.caremonkey.com/api/docs/

I'm failing to work out how to send this header in the ImportJSON function.

I've read through the documentation, tested the API with PostMan (success) and tried a few variations of the function call below. =importjson(https://groups.caremonkey.com/api/v2/organizations/_ORG_ID_/child_groups, "authorize=*tokenkey*")

I've also tried the ImportJSONViaPost function (even though the operation is a GET), as well as changing Line 118 from 
  postOptions["method"] = "POST"; 
to
  postOptions["method"] = "GET";

I just can't figure out a way to send a header as part of the request.

Can anyone help me figure out what I've missed please?

Cheers,
Tim

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Andronicus

I've read through the documentation, google searched for solutions, tested the API with PostMan (success) and tried a few variations of the function call below.

=importjson(https://groups.caremonkey.com/api/v2/organizations/<ORG_ID>/child_groups, "authorize=<tokenkey>")

I've also tried the *ImportJSONViaPost* function (even though the operation is a GET), as well as changing Line 118 from 
    postOptions["method"] = "POST";
to
    postOptions["method"] = "GET";

I can't see any options to send a header as part of the request.

Comment: Welcome. It's a bit difficult to figure out what you've missed when one can't (for security reasons??) reproduce the actual example. Have you looked at the [CareMonkey API](https://groups.caremonkey.com/api/docs/#/Organizations/get_organizations__organization_id__child_groups) which you can test online? Have you asked CareMonkey whether their API integrates with Google Sheets? Have you considered a `doGet(e)` function in an apps script?